# Index out of bound. How to resolve

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace test
{
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the Principal: ");
        int principal = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the rate: ");
        int rate = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        int a = rate / 100;
        int b = a * principal;
        int x = b + principal;

        int[] sample = {};

        Console.WriteLine("How long do you want the loop to run: ");
        int loop = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

       // StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i <= loop; i++)
        {

            sample[x] = x;

           // sb.AppendLine(x.ToString());
            b = a * x;
            x = b + x;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(sample);
    }
 }
}
```

Hi, I just started learning C# and the topic that my teacher discussed today was arrays. So I decided to create a simple Interest Calculator, but it's giving me

> "System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array."

Comment: FYI `Console.WriteLine(sample)` is not going to give you useful info.  Instead use `Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", sample));`

Comment: I did exactly as you told me but it's still showing the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this

```
    Console.WriteLine("How long do you want the loop to run: ");
    int loop = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    int[] sample = new int[loop];
```

to set the length from the array

and change your for loop from (int i = 0; i **<=** loop; i++) to (int i = 0; i **<** loop; i++)

Comment: It's still showing the same error. Btw what does removing the '=' operator have to do with anything.

Comment: @Fakhr Because the loop starts at 0 you want to stop before it hits loop if you want to loop that many times. So if it's 4 you want it to loop for 0, 1, 2, 3 and not for 0, 1, 2, 3, 4

Answer (score 1):

You must allocate enough space: `int[] sample = new int[loop];`

Arrays are indexed from zero in C#, so if your array has `X` length, then the last element's index is `X-1`. So your for loop should be: `for (int i = 0; i < loop; i++)`

You are indexing your `sample` array with `x`, but I think you wan't to index it with `i`. `sample[i] = x;`

You are printing an array, but it will output `System.Int32[]`. I think you want to print out the elements in the array.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the Principal: ");
    int principal = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the rate: ");
    int rate = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    int a = rate / 100;
    int b = a * principal;
    int x = b + principal;

    Console.WriteLine("How long do you want the loop to run: ");
    int loop = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    int[] sample = new int[loop];

    for (int i = 0; i < loop; i++)
    {
        sample[i] = x;
        b = a * x;
        x = b + x;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < sample.Length; i++)
        Console.WriteLine(sample[i]);
}
```

Comment: It's working but it's not giving me the correct output. It's just printing 1000 ten time. If I give principle = 1000, rate = 5 and loop = 10 then I want the answer to be:

Comment: 1. 1050.0   2. 1102.5   3. 1157.62  and so on. I first wrote this code in Python and it worked perfectly.

Comment: if `rate = 5`, then `int a = rate / 100` will 0. :)

Comment: A very embarrassing mistake on my part. Thank you for pointing it out.